# Place view above scrollview

Tags: android

I have a scrollview in my android app that supports overscroll and has a nice bounce effect. What I would like to do is add a view that is initially hidden to the user, but if they scroll up beyond the initial view, then they can see it. How can I do this? Is it possible to do this using just xml?

Answer (score 0):

You can place the initial view and the additional view in a `LinearLayout`, and when the scroll view is created, you can immediately scroll downwards to the initial view. You can set the initial scroll offset using the xml attribute `android:scrollY`.

Answer (score 0):

By code you can definitely  achieve this. In this sample code I have 15 buttons in srollview. And hide 1st button for initial display.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final ScrollView hscrollViewMain = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.sview);

    hscrollViewMain.post(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {

            Button bt2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
            int nY_Pos = bt2.getTop(); 
            // scroll to top of bt2
            hscrollViewMain.scrollTo(0,nY_Pos);
        }
    }); 
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/sview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 >

<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:id="@+id/bt1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Button 2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 3" />
                .
                .
                .
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 15" />
    </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Still facing same issue?